# accessing secondary domain/site from a domain's subfolder

Tags: proxy, nginx

we have custom production system using aws/ec2/nginx/php-fpm on example.com
we'd like to set up a blog under example.com/blog (potentially using a wordpress CMS); however for security reasons we'd like to run the wordpress (or whichever CMS we'll use) on a separate ec2 instance (server) to minimise impact if the CMS get's compromised.

So essentially https://example.com/blog should act as a proxy URL for the blogging website, which will run on another server.

I'm struggling to define this in a few keywords to find an answer on google, so a pointer or a solution would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a new location in the Nginx configuration file, for example:

```
location /blog {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://anotherserver:{PORT};
}
```

replace 'anotherserver:{PORT}' with the actual IP address and port.